# What is the equivalent of "eval" function in math notations?

Tags: notation

Given two sets $X$ and $Y$, and a function $f : X \to Y$,
would it be correct to write:
\begin{equation}
\forall y \in \{a,b,c\} : \textit{Fy} \triangleq \{ x \in X \mid f(x) = y \}.
\end{equation}
as an equivalent of:
\begin{equation}
\textit{Fa} \triangleq \{ x \in X \mid f(x) = a \}.\\
\textit{Fb} \triangleq \{ x \in X \mid f(x) = b \}.\\
\textit{Fc} \triangleq \{ x \in X \mid f(x) = c \}.\\
\end{equation}

I'm basically looking for an equivalent of the evaluation function.

**N.B.** I don't want to write $F_y$ instead of $Fy$.

Thanks for you answers.

NS

Comment: See [Inverse image (or: *preimage*)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_(mathematics)#Inverse_image): $f^{-1}[ \{ a,b,c \} ]$.

Comment: Why not use the standard notation $f^{-1}(a)$, or to be strict, $f^{-1}(\{a\})$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On usually writes

$$f^{-1}[y] := \{x\in X\mid f(x)=y\}.$$

It is called the "[preimage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_%28mathematics%29#Inverse_image)" (or "inverse image"). You can compute the preimage of a set as well, i.e.

$$f^{-1}[\tilde Y]:=\{x\in X\mid f(x)\in \tilde Y\}.$$

Then $f^{-1}[y]$ is equivalent to $f^{-1}[\{y\}]$. When it is known that the resulting set contains exactly a single element (when $f$ is bijective/one-to-one), then one often writes $f^{-1}(y)$ instead, and associates the result with this single element. This is called the "[inverse function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function)".

> **Note**: Taste might differ and the use of square brackets and parantheses for the preimage is not standard. I prefer the notation presented here, because it is clear whether the result is a set or a single element.

Comment: I had not seen $f^{-1}[y] $ for $f^{-1}[\{y\}]$, but with the square brackets there should be no confusion. As an aside, when I was first taught about this I was shown a nonstandard unambiguous notation $f^{<}(B)$ instead of $f^{-1}[B] $, so that $f^{<}:\mathbf{P}(Y)\to\mathbf{P}(X)$ was a genuine function.

Comment: Thank you for your clear answer. I will use this notation. However, I still wonder if there is a mathematical concise way to say, for example: "for each $x \in \{a,b,c\}$, we write $Fx$ instead of $F(x)$. Basically, I want to substitute $x$ in the name of the variable; hence my question about the existence of an "eval" function equivalent.

Comment: @N.Short I am not familiar with any "eval"-functions, so can you explain a bit more what you need exactly?

Comment: An "eval" fct. (in certain programming languages) is a fct. that evaluates a string (an array of characters) as if it was code. eval("a=b+c") is the same as running a=b+c. 

I thought it was a good analogy with my problem, since what I want to do is find a math. concise way of writing: I want to substitute all $F(x)$ by $Fx$ where $x$ is the var. But, problem is my variable $x$ is embedded into the name of my vars.

Simply said, I want to have var. names $Fa$, $Fb$, $Fc$ for $F(a)$, $F(b)$, $F(c)$, & explain this desire with a math formula that starts with: $\forall x \in \{a,b,c\}…$

Comment: @N.Short I think you should explain a bit more about your use case. It might be that $\forall x\in\{a,b,c\}:Fx ...$ is totally fine, but it also seems that you are constructing a character string rather than a math formula, in which case you have to state which part of the string are characters and which are placeholders for the actual variable.

Comment: @M.Winter Yes, I am constructing a string that stands for a variable name. I want to replace some standard notations with more compact ones for the sake of readability. After some thought, I think it's better just to explain it with text as it would probably be too long/complicated to do it with a math formula (I wouldn't have answered my question though).